# How can I pass data from the directive of a parent element to child elements?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, promise, angular-promise

I am attempting to write a directive to resolve promises and add data to the scope so that I can lazily load data into child elements from an API.

Through console.logging I am certain that I am resolving the promise and getting my expected data, but nothing updates on the page. I am assuming that dynamically adding to the scope from inside a directive is causing my problem.

The directive seems fairly trivial and I know that the promise is getting resolved:

```
app.directive('resolver', () => {
  return {
        restrict: "AEC",
        scope: {
            outName: "@",
            promise: "&",
            defaultVal: "="
        },
        link: function ($scope, element, attrs) {
            var promise = $scope.promise,
                outName = $scope.outName || 'myPromise',
                defaultVal = $scope.defaultVal || {};

            $scope[outName] = defaultVal;

            promise().then(data => {
                $scope[outName] = data;
            });
        }
    }
});
```

I was hoping that this would let me do something like the following:

```
<li class="company-entry" ng-repeat="company in currentFeed.companies" resolver promise="getPreview(company.companyId)" out-name="profile" default-val="{name:'Loading...',description:'',images:[],sources:[]}">
    ...
    <a ui-sref="company.feed({ id: company.companyId })" class="company-name">{{ profile.name || 'foo' }}</a>
    </li>
```

Firstly, I have `profile.name || 'foo'` in order to test if the default-val part of my code would work; since it stays at foo, not even the default value gets placed into `profile`.

Secondly, after the promise is resolved, I should be setting `profile` to the data, but the page does not updating.

Adding a `$scope.$apply()` causes me to get rootscope update already in progress errors.

Is there any way to accomplish what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would solve this differently. Instead of building this into a directive you can easily produce a thenable that automatically unwraps just like ngResource does.

Let's consider an example: You have an array you need to fetch online with a `getArray()` function which returns a promise and makes an http request.

Normally you do:

```
getArray().then(function(result){
    $scope.data = result;
});
```

Which I assume you're trying to avoid because it's a lot to write if everything in your scope is like this. The trick promises used to use and ngResource still uses in Angular is the following:

- Return an empty result, which is also a promise
- Whenever that promise resolves, update the result on the screen.

For example, our `getArray()` could look something like:

```
function getArray(){
    var request = $http(...); // actual API request
    var result = []
    result.then = request.then; // make the result a promise too
    result.then(function(resp){ 
        // update _the same_ object, since objects are passed by reference
        // this will also update every place we've send the object to
        resp.data.forEach(function(el){ result.push(el); });
    });
    return result;
}
```

Now if you call `getArray()` and assign the result to a scope variable, whenever the promise resolves it will update the value.

Comment: Well, the reason I was trying to build it into a directive is because I basically have a ton of locations where I want to pull down associated data based on a particular trait about that entry; in this case, I am looking to download a preview of a company from a location that only has the ID of the company, without injecting that preview into the actual original data. I will see if I can adapt what you said though to better fit into my workflow

Comment: @PhilBarresi it's perfectly possible to automate the process of creating objects and adding the promise `then` to them - in fact Angular would do this on its own in versions before 1.2

Comment: After it all sank in I realized that this is definitely the right way of looking at it; the angular way is to do data things with the data and not mess up by abusing the display. Someone tossed me this excellent plunker that gives another great demonstration of how to implement this using your recommendation (http://plnkr.co/edit/H11igQf7OXmoQIRUEkLP?p=info).